# How to add pacing dynamically in a HP LoadRunner script

Tags: loadrunner

I am working on a performance testing project using HP load runner, my requirement is to add pacing dynamically through script for each and every iteration. I did lost of research, but couldn't find one solution for this. Can someone please help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an LR function in load runner LR_thinktime(), it takes second as parameter input. Example: LR_thinktime(5), will make your script think for 5 seconds. You can use this function to induce required pacing in you vugen script. Have some logic to calculate pacing in seconds and pass it to LR_thinktime(). Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Combine this with a variable (of random type, with a range if needed) and you have the desired 'variable pacing'.  Something along the lines of `LR_thinktime( LR_evalstring("{variable_name}") );` - Exact syntax may change as it's been a while since I wrote my last LR script

Comment: lr_thinktime() will not result in a constant pacing model as the value will be subject to the run time settings for the skew imposed on your thinktime +/- your calculated number in your thinktime function.   sleep(<milliseconds>); is unaffected by the run time settings related to think time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want actual script pacing and # of seconds is accurate enough you could use something like this -

```
int i, iPacing;

iPacing = 5; // Number of seconds to wait between passes of the script

lr_save_datetime("%H%M%S",DATE_NOW,"dCurTime");

i = atoi(lr_eval_string("{dCurTime}")) - atoi(lr_eval_string("{dStartTime}"));       

if (i >= iPacing){
   Action1();
   Action2();
   Action3();   
   lr_save_datetime("%H%M%S",DATE_NOW,"dStartTime");
}
```

That very last line also goes in the vuser.init to set the initial start time.

Comment: BTW - This will work fine for a test in the same day but will need to change the time setting to include more info if running the test past day/month/year boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code at the beginning or at the end of your action block:

lr_thinktime(atoi(lr_eval_string("{paramname}")));

paramname is the name of a parameter which will be a random number type. you can easily create a parameter with the help of parameter file settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want direct controlled pacing which will not be affected by your thinktime settings then you can use sleep(milliseconds); for a delay.   You should also be able to pull the iteration number using a parameter.

I have used this type of model for a decayed pacing model with a sleep() at the end of the iteration with a fixed value divided by iteration number.